# How to mark views in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, initialization

I have an app with a list view. The listview works fine. The problem starts, when I want the list to start with some of the rows marked.  I can mark a row, if I press on it. But, don't seem to find a way to mark any row on initialization.

This is my code:

```
listViewOfBluetooth = getListView();
setInitialEnabledDevices();
  listViewOfBluetooth.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String chosenBluetoothDevice = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();

      BluetoothEnableOrDisable(view, chosenBluetoothDevice);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), chosenBluetoothDevice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      editor.putString("bluetooth_name_from_list1", chosenBluetoothDevice);
      editor.putBoolean("have_the_cars_bluetooth", true);
      editor.commit();
      Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, ParkOGuardActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
}

public static void setInitialEnabledDevices(){
    int length = listViewOfBluetooth.getChildCount();
    View view = null;
    String first = prefs.getString("bluetooth_name_from_list0", "");
    String second = prefs.getString("bluetooth_name_from_list1", "");
    String third = prefs.getString("bluetooth_name_from_list2", "");
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        view = listViewOfBluetooth.getChildAt(i);
        if(view.equals(first) || view.equals(second) || view.equals(third)) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
    }       
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: i use listadapter: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, arrayOfBluetoothDevicesNames));

Comment: Why don't you create a Adapter which extends ArrayAdapter?
And override getView() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achive this by using custom adapter. Here is the workaround.

- Initialize your custom adapter
- Add some flag for marked device names.
- Override the `getView()` & check for the flag. And set the background of the list item accordingly.

Reply if you don't get it or face any complexity.

**Update:**

Here is a sample adapter. I didn't compile the code. So there might be some errors.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<String> deviceNames;
    ArrayList<Boolean> selected;
    Context context;

    public TestAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        deviceNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        selected = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    }

    public void addDeviceToList(String deviceName, boolean isSelected)
    {
        deviceNames.add(deviceName);
        selected.add(isSelected);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return deviceNames.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return deviceNames.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(deviceNames.get(position));
        if(selected.get(position) == true)
        {
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Now create adapter object and set the adapter to listView. And add single item by calling `addDeviceToList()` method.

Comment: im new here... so, its not clear to me.
i hope you can show me some code but will understand if its asking to much...

Answer (score 0):

That seems to nasty 
but i think you want to modify the views inside listview before loading it

The thing is, that your list won't have children as long as the list is not displayed to the user.so you may not modify the view before showing it to the user

But if you really need to communicate with the views on a such low level you could try to attach a scroll listener to your list:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        Now edit this view 

    }
}
```