# Android : clear listview in Listadapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how to clear my listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832102/how-to-clear-my-listview-in-android)

In android,  i have used a listadapter, simple adapter and passed an array and i want to clear the listview contents? Instead of clearing , it is appending the records to my listview.

Comment: youradapter.clear();   this clears the items in the listview

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Grab my Custom adapter from here. [TestAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828657/how-to-mark-views-in-a-listview/10828782#10828782)

Now add a method like this..

```
public void clearAdapter()
    {
        deviceNames.clear();
        selected.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now call `youListAdapter.clearAdapter()` from you Activity.

Comment: I have a new idea about this topic. If you are sure your adapter refreshing processes, and your break points tell you that 'actually everything is okay', you should control your activity and fragment stack. Because if you have one more than same activities or same fragments in your app stack, actually your processes are success but that activity or that fragment is under the its other same sibling :)

Answer (score 15):

Simply write listView.setAdapter(null)

Answer (score 2):

Use `notifydataSetInValidated()` on your adapter  to notify your listview that the data set is not longer valid.  or set your addapter to null : `l.setAdapter(null);`