# how to clear my listview in android

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have included my ListAdapter in my EMPLOYEE class.And list1 contains the values of Empname,
Eno,Salary fetched from webservices.Now after displaying the 5 records in the employee 
screen...when I click on Depatrment Activity and come back to Employee ... the initial
5 records are appended to the list and now 10 records are present and so on .... the process is going on like this...
Please help me so as no duplicates are appended and it has to refresh the list.

Note : clear() or notifydatasetchanged(), invalidate() are not working.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list1,
R.layout.employee, new String[] { "EmpName","Eno", "Salary" }, new int[]
 {R.id.ename, R.id.eno,R.id.sal});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
Listview lv = getListView();

    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            pos = position;
            registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        }

    });


    TextView tvdept = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Department); 
    tvdept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Employee.this, Department.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you put clear() or notifydatasetchanged(), invalidate() before setListAdapter(adapter)?

Comment: You mean like this:   lv.clear(); or lv.notifydatasetchanged(); .....yes i did its not working....they don't actually work with this list adapter

Comment: You should show us the whole method containing that list.  Is it in your `onCreate` method?

Comment: yes .. it is in the oncreate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, it's difficult to be sure, but I'll hazard a guess...

When you leave an activity and come back, the framework tries to restore you to where you were using the `savedInstanceState` bundle.  It uses this to re-create where you last were in that activity.  It sounds like you have set up the list in the `onCreate` method and haven't checked for a `savedInstanceState` bundle, so when you come back to the activity the framework is restoring your list and then proceeds into your code and re-creates the list (in this case adding the same data again).

Try wrapping your list creation code in an `if` that checks for the existence of the `savedInstanceState` bundle.

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       // do your list setup here
   }
 }
```

Using that, if you come back to the activity and the framework saved your state, it will simply restore it and not run through your list creation code.

I know this doesn't answer the actual question, but it should solve the root issue (duplicating list data on return to activity).